# How to call an apex class from process builder

Tags: apex, soql, process-builder, invocable-method

I would like to update a specific set of fields based on owners on opportunities.

We wrote an apex trigger and some other classes. Everything is working fine. But when a user changes an account owner with opportunities owners, the code is not working.

So, for the above requirement, I've created a process in Process Builder with this criteria: account owner is changes = true. I want to call an apex class like below. But, it is not working or not throwing any errors.

I read from the docs that when an account owner changes, opportunity triggers wouldn't fire.

So, I've created a process in Process Builder where when an account owner changes, I do a field update in the related opportunity records.

Is there any possibility other than the above field update?

For Reference i posted my apex classes.

```
public class OpportunityTeamMapping {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void UpdateOpportunityTeamMapping(List<Id> accountIds) 
    {
        List<opportunity> opportunities = [Select Id 
                                           from opportunity where opportunity.Id 
                                           in :accountIds];
        FssTeamUpdate.FssteamMappingopps(opportunities);
    }
}
```

2nd main class

```
  public static void FssteamMappingopps(List<Opportunity>  TriggerOpportunities)
{
    /** 
     * This method is to update Picklists based on Lead owner
     * It verfies lead owners with the names in custom labels of respective teams.
     * It updates the picklists value with respective team names whenever username
     * in the corresponding custom label 
    */
    /** @var ownerMap - map of Owner Ids to their matching Owner Record */
    Map<Id,User> ownerMap;
    /** @var oppOwnerIds - set of Opportunity Owner Ids from the inserted / updated records */
    Set<Id> oppOwnerIds = new Set<Id>();
    /** @var nameOfOwner - will hold the name of the Oppturnity Owner */
    String nameOfOwner;
    String owners,ownerstemp,ownerinfinity,ownerwolfpack,ownerfalcon,ownergame,ownerwarriors,ownerUSteam;
    /** @strings are used to retrive the usernames from custom labels  */
    owners          = Label.Special_Team;
    ownerstemp      = Label.Avengers;
    ownerinfinity   = Label.Infinity;
    ownerwolfpack   = Label.Wolfpack;
    ownerfalcon     = Label.Falcon;
    ownergame       = Label.Game;
    ownerwarriors   = Label.Warriors;
    ownerUSteam     = Label.Team_Us;

    /**@Arrays to split the usernames in custom labels based on ',' */
    List<String>specialteam = owners.split(',');
    List<String>Avengers    = ownerstemp.split(',');
    List<String>Infinity    = ownerinfinity.split(',');
    List<String>Wolfpack    = ownerwolfpack.split(',');
    List<String>Falcon      = ownerfalcon.split(',');
    List<String>Game        = ownergame.split(',');
    List<String>Warriors    = ownerwarriors.split(',');
    List<String>USteam      = ownerUSteam.split(',');

    for(Opportunity opps : TriggerOpportunities) 
    { 
        // loop through all updated/inserted opps
        // add the owner id to the set of owner ids
        oppOwnerIds.add(opps.OwnerId);      
    } 

    ownerMap = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id IN :oppOwnerIds]);

    for(Opportunity opps : TriggerOpportunities)
    { 
        // loop through the updated/inserted opps again
        // use the opportunity owner id to grab the record from the map

        nameOfOwner = ownerMap.get(opps.OwnerId).Name; 

        for(String s:specialteam) 
        {
            if(s.equals( nameOfOwner) && opps.StageName !='Closed Won' && opps.StageName !='Closed Lost') 
            { 
                /** updates all the picklist values based on lead owner and update count  */
                opps.FSS_Team__c='Special';
                opps.FSS_Team_Lead__c='Alvin Nash';
                opps.FSS_Group__c ='Team A';
                Countopp = 1;
            }
        }

        for(String s:Avengers) 
        {
            if(s.equals( nameOfOwner) && opps.StageName !='Closed Won' && opps.StageName !='Closed Lost') 
            {
                /** updates all the picklist values based on lead owner and update count  */
                opps.FSS_Team__c='Avengers';
                opps.FSS_Team_Lead__c='Brenden Naismith';
                opps.FSS_Group__c ='Team C';
                Countopp = 1;
            }
        }
        for(String s:Infinity) 
        {
            if(s.equals( nameOfOwner) && opps.StageName !='Closed Won' && opps.StageName !='Closed Lost') 
            { 
                /** updates all the picklist values based on lead owner and update count  */
                opps.FSS_Team__c='Infinity';
                opps.FSS_Team_Lead__c='Robin Rico';
                opps.FSS_Group__c ='Team C';
                Countopp = 1;
            }
        }
        for(String s:Wolfpack)
        {
            if(s.equals( nameOfOwner) && opps.StageName !='Closed Won' && opps.StageName !='Closed Lost')
            {
                /** updates all the picklist values based on lead owner and update count  */
                opps.FSS_Team__c='Wolfpack';
                opps.FSS_Team_Lead__c='David Pedro';
                opps.FSS_Group__c ='Team B';
                Countopp = 1;
            }
        }
        for(String s:Warriors)
        {
            if(s.equals( nameOfOwner) && opps.StageName !='Closed Won' && opps.StageName !='Closed Lost')
            { 
                /** updates all the picklist values based on lead owner and update count  */
                opps.FSS_Team__c='Warriors';
                opps.FSS_Team_Lead__c='Jonathan Cristo';
                opps.FSS_Group__c ='Team C';
                Countopp = 1;
            }
        }
        for(String s:USteam) 
        {
            if(s.equals( nameOfOwner) && opps.StageName !='Closed Won' && opps.StageName !='Closed Lost') 
            { 
                /** updates all the picklist values based on lead owner and update count  */
                opps.FSS_Team__c='US Team';
                opps.FSS_Team_Lead__c='Jeff Smith';
                opps.FSS_Group__c ='Team US';
                Countopp = 1;
            }
        }
        if(Countopp == 0 && opps.StageName !='Closed Won' && opps.StageName !='Closed Lost')
        {
            /** updates all the picklist values based on lead owner and update count  */
            opps.FSS_Team__c=null;
            opps.FSS_Team_Lead__c=null;
            opps.FSS_Group__c =null;
            Countopp = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are querying opportunities with account ids..You should change query to "FROM Opportunity Where AccountId IN: accountids"